# Can't seem to be able to get images to overlay with each other

Tags: html, css, image, slider, overlay

I've been trying to make my own automatic image slider, but for some reason I can't seem to get the 3 images that I want shown by default in the correct positions. I want one main image in the middle of a div, and then two more shown on the right (with a smaller width) , cut off with an overflow: hidden. I've tried everything as far as my knowledge of CSS and HTML go and just can't get it looking right. The image below shows what I am trying to accomplish using HTML and CSS.

Image: [Very Artistic Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcJ6B.png)

[HTML & CSS](http://pastebin.com/GywWa3Yh)

Comment: can you post the code in your request?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated my post. @DanieleFois

Comment: it's better if you paste your code inside the post. 
Anyway, you have width: 0% in the #main rule that's only one of the errors

Comment: what should it do?move the images?on click?intervals?

Comment: Can you setup a codepen or jsfiddle rather then just pasting the code on pastebin?

Comment: I've created a JS fiddle for you but for future reference just go to https://jsfiddle.net/, paste your code in the appropriate boxes (html, css, javascript...), click save, then you can copy the link here for everyone to see. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfhjks5a/

Comment: @DanieleFois I just made a more updated version of that jsfiddle including my jquery which explains why my main has a 0% width.

Comment: @damianocelent I haven't tried to get any of the movement working yet and I believe I can probably figure that bit out, I just can't get the positioning of the images correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have done a flexbox solution for this:

```
#image1 {-webkit-order: 0;
-ms-flex-order: 0;
order: 0;
-webkit-flex: 8 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 8 1 auto;
flex: 8 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;}
```

This is the relevant part.

This is the other relevant part:

```
#image2:hover{
-webkit-order: 0;
-ms-flex-order: 0;
order: 0;
-webkit-flex: 98 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 98 1 auto;
flex: 98 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;
}
```

This is quite complicated to explain, best to check a tutorial on flexbox, it's the layout future anyway.

Here is the link to the pen.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ZBbjOp

Answer (score 0):

This is messy, but I think it's a rough idea of what you're looking for.

```css
#main {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
 
#sliderImage {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    right: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 40%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
}
 
#image1, #image2, #image3 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
 
#image2 {
    left:105px;
    z-index:-1;
    
}

#image3 {
    left:210px;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="sliderImage">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports" alt="image 1" id="image1"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports" alt="image 2" id="image2"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/sports" alt="image 3" id="image3"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With the 'left' property for the #image2 and #image3 of the css, wouldn't that make it so that it doesn't look right (or the same) on different sized browsers?

Comment: Are you talking about pixel size? Different screens may have different pixel sizes (resolution) which would make it look slightly different I suppose.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was talking about, I've been trying to use percents as much as possible in order to make it work on most resolutions

Comment: I don't think you're going to see a huge difference between  different screens. I'm on quite a few major web development projects at the moment and I see positioning based on pixels all the time. That being said, it's definitely a good idea to have those kind of things in mind. I'm sure you could redo this with percentages or ems or whatever but I just hacked this together real quick and percentages can be weird with images. Here's a post on resizing images based on percentages if that's something you want to do www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself

Comment: Note that images will also render differently based on different screen resolutions.

Comment: I always dread to use relative positions, especially when php includes are used. However, as long it is used in modules, it's an easy fix for mobile displays.